# VB.Net : Create a Recordset with manual inputs and GetRows() methods failing

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object, adodb, recordset

First time writing on a forum but this one really left me no choice and it seems that nobody had the same problem as I have... not a good sign...

I have a project to use the COM Server of a software we use internally and need to use one of their built-in function which requires a recordset as an input and return another recordset with the results (important because I need to **stick with the recordset**).

Here's breifly what I tried. I create a recordset from scratch and fill it with some hardcoded data just for testing purposes. Once my recordset is filled, I want to look at the data just to be sure everything works well, but I'll have to do the same eventually with my results.

**The problem I get is it seems that the GetRows() method return only 1 row every time depending on the last row I moved to. But once it's called, I cannot get the other records.** I'm already using the GetRows() method with an actual query and still with an ADODB recordset and it works perfectly. Building a recodset from scratch seems less easy.

I need to put all my data in an object to work with it. But even if I want to use only a recordset, I cannot access to all data in it. Very fustrating... something I'm missing here...

**Error I get: either bof or eof is true or the current record has been deleted**

Thanks in advance,

```
Public Function GetFDBData() As Boolean

        Dim filtersView As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rsFields(1) As Object
        Dim fieldsAPT(3, 1) As Object
        Dim dataView As Object
        Dim i As Integer

        rsFields(0) = "Field Name"
        rsFields(1) = "Filter"

        fieldsAPT(0, 0) = "ISIN"
        fieldsAPT(0, 1) = "=CA89*"
        fieldsAPT(1, 0) = "Currency"
        fieldsAPT(1, 1) = "=CAD"
        fieldsAPT(2, 0) = "Line"
        fieldsAPT(2, 1) = "=Bond"
        fieldsAPT(3, 0) = "Redemption Date"
        fieldsAPT(3, 1) = "=20230*"

        Try
            'Build the recordset containing APT fields and filters (in the same variable fieldsAPT)
            filtersView.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
            filtersView.Fields.Append(rsFields(0), ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, 30)
            filtersView.Fields.Append(rsFields(1), ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, 30)
            filtersView.Open(, , ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

            Dim fieldAPT(1)
            For i = 0 To UBound(fieldsAPT)
                fieldAPT(0) = fieldsAPT(i, 0)
                Console.WriteLine(fieldAPT(0))              'Works fine
                fieldAPT(1) = fieldsAPT(i, 1)
                Console.WriteLine(fieldAPT(1))              'Works fine
                filtersView.AddNew(rsFields, fieldAPT)
                filtersView.Update()
                Console.WriteLine(filtersView.RecordCount)  'I can see 1 2 3 4 no problem here
            Next i

            Dim xx As Integer = filtersView.RecordCount     'xx is 4 as expected
            Console.WriteLine("xx: " & xx)
            filtersView.MoveFirst()                         'Will move to the first record or whatever record
            'dataView = filtersView.GetRows()               'I expected this line to work, but same results

            For i = 0 To xx - 1
                dataView = filtersView.GetRows()
                Console.WriteLine(dataView(i, 0).ToString)      'ISIN, normal
                Console.WriteLine(filtersView.RecordCount)      'Still equals 4, normal
                Console.WriteLine(filtersView.BOF)              'False, normal
                Console.WriteLine(filtersView.EOF)              'True, which is NOT normal
                Console.WriteLine(filtersView.AbsolutePosition) 'Get -3 not sure why (position 1 related to 4???)
                Console.WriteLine(filtersView.MaxRecords)       'Get 0 not sure why
                filtersView.MoveNext()                          '!!!! Here is where it fails !!!! Cannot go more than i=0
            Next i

            GetFDBData = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            GetFDBData = False
        Finally
            'Clear memory
            filtersView.Close()
        End Try
End Function
```

Also, if I do this,

```
Dim xx As Integer = filtersView.RecordCount     'xx is 4 as expected
            Console.WriteLine("xx: " & xx)
            filtersView.MoveLast()
```

Instead of

```
 Dim xx As Integer = filtersView.RecordCount     'xx is 4 as expected
                Console.WriteLine("xx: " & xx)
                filtersView.MoveFirst()
```

It will return "Redemption date" in the for loop after. Which makes sense because it is the last record. But puting movefirst even after does'nt solve the issue... still one row only. So the data is there, but I really can't extract one line and one line only...

Comment: Did you try to use filtersView.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseServer instead of filtersView.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient ?

Comment: Yes, same result. At first it was ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseServer

Comment: This line is strange. What is it supposed to be? filtersView.Open(, , ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

Comment: It's just to open the recordset. filtersView.Open() also work if I specify before the lock and cursor type. It would work even if I don't specify but will put default value..

Comment: Why are you using adodb recordsets with vb.net? The older recordset objects are really only for compatibility, to make it faster to update old code, and it's been that way for more than a decade. Don't use it for anything new.

Comment: Joel, the function in the COM Server I'm trying to access needs a recordset as an input. If there is a way to create a recordset without a adodb it might indeed works. But cannot use datagrid, really not sure it will work with my project. But it might be the next step... At the same time, this should works, and it "partially" works... Also I'm new to vb.net so if there is a better way I'm ready to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your cursor type to adOpenDynamic

EDIT: OK,your line
    dataView = filtersView.GetRows()

is causing your cursor to travel to the end of the recordset, try moving it outside your loop and following it with a new MoveFirst like so

```
     filtersView.MoveFirst()                         'Will move to the first record or whatever record
     'dataView = filtersView.GetRows()               'I expected this line to work, but same results

     dataView = filtersView.GetRows()
     filtersView.MoveFirst()

     Dim sTemp As String = ""
     For i = 0 To xx - 1
        'Console.WriteLine(dataView(i, 0).ToString)      'ISIN, normal
        Console.WriteLine(filtersView.RecordCount)      'Still equals 4, normal
        Console.WriteLine(filtersView.BOF)              'False, normal
        Console.WriteLine(filtersView.EOF)              'True, which is NOT normal
        Console.WriteLine(filtersView.AbsolutePosition) 'Get -3 not sure why (position 1 related to 4???)
        Console.WriteLine(filtersView.MaxRecords)       'Get 0 not sure why
        sTemp = sTemp & "(" & dataView(0, i).ToString & ", " & dataView(1, i).ToString & ")"
        filtersView.MoveNext()                          '!!!! Here is where it fails !!!! Cannot go more than i=0
     Next i
     Console.WriteLine(sTemp)
```

You can verify that by checking the value of filtersView.AbsolutePosition immediately before and after your call to GetRows

Also, you are reversing rows and columns in dataView, move i to the second subscript position. I put it in a temporary string to make it easier to view in the debugger.

Comment: Position is 1 and then -3 after the GetRows(),even if I take it out of the loop. but dataView is still one row only

Comment: Try moving i to the second subscript position when you access dataView, I made the change above and now I'm getting all 4 of your rows out.

Comment: Ok got it. I still had the filtersView.MoveNext() in the loop. Make sense. I know it was something almost obvious. Thx Robert for your help!!!

Comment: Great, glad I could help, S.O. has saved my bacon more than once, nice to give back :-) and your complete code block allowed me to drop it directly in & debug.

Comment: I learned everything from this kind of forum. One year ago, I didn't even know how to open the macro window in Excel. I'd notice how important the questions must be well asked to get quick and good answers. These forums are very well built and people like you contribute a lot to beginning developpers like me. Thanks again, Cheers